# git garbage colleciton using git version 1.8.3.1 and slow git.log

Tags: java, git, jgit

I would like to know if the `git.gc().setAggressive(true).call();` actually worked correctly on the siteRepo. How can I measure its effect programatically? I am using git version 1.8.3.1

```
// aggressively optimize the publication repository
    
siteRepo = new File(gitLocation+publication);
if (siteRepo.exists()){
                git = Git.open(siteRepo);
                git.gc().setAggressive(true).call();
                println("*** garbage collection for repo :" +gitLocation+publication);
              }
```

I was able to measure it using `du -h --max-depth=0 *`

```
146M    ius -> using git.gc on the repo
3.7G    ius -> without git.gc on the repo
```

git.log unfortunatelly takes a long time on this repo even after git.gc. Is there an additional way to optimizes git.log?

Comment: jgit is its own implementation of Git. Unless it uses a shell to literally run `git gc`, your Git version is not relevant. (I don't know if it literally runs `git gc`, in which case your Git version does become relevant.) Probably your jgit version is more important here.

Comment: Do you know if git improved its git performance for searching the git commit tree in higher versions?

Comment: Git itself has had continuous work done to it to improve its performance and to add new features. I have no idea whether JGit has had such work.